# Envio de informações mobile para web

Tags: android, python, aplicação-web

Bom dia meus caros!

Quero coletar alguns dados e enviar algumas informações do Mobile (Android) para um site WEB que estou desenvolvendo com (Python+Django). Porém eu não sei o nome desse processo de envio do celular. 
Como se chama o envio de dados do celular para o meu site web? 
Que ai eu consigo fazer uma pesquisa na internet e conseguir fazer..

Então a pergunta é.. "Qual é o nome do processo que realiza o envio de dados coletados pelo celular, para um site web? "

Agradeço.

Comment: Eu creio que você esteja procurando a palavra "Requisição" mas cuidado. Entre plataformas as requisições são feitas para API e não para um site de fato. Acho que você deveria reformular sua pergunta ou procurar um pouco mais na internet para achar uma soluções.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você vai fazer uma requisição HTTP (HTTP Request) - mais especificamente, normalmente usando um dos métodos "POST, PUT ou PATCH" para modificar dados ou "GET" apenas pra recuperar dados. Então, em alguns documentos "Requisição POST HTTP" pode estar abreviado para "POST".

Em outros lugares você pode encontrar a palavra "query" para encurtar ainda mais ("Vou fazer uma query ao servidor").

Se o seu app android estiver em Javascript ou alguma tecnologia similar, esse tipo de requisição pode estar documentada também como "ajax" ou "requisição assíncrona".